# How to match either `?` or `/` with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string at every position that contains a `?` or a `/`. I am not very familiar with regular expressions, so this is giving me quite some trouble, since I am not sure where and what to escape. It should be something like this:

```
let uri = '/some/random/path?param=1234'
let arr = uri.split(/ ?|/ /);
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj [Yep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: Just a fun regex where you do not have to escape neither `?` nor `/`: `let arr = uri.split(RegExp("[?/]"))`. BTW, you have not specified what you want to get as output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var uri = '/some/random/path?param=1234';
var split = uri.split(/([?\/])/);
console.log(split);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/0rjw01ch/

Comment: maybe a match. `str.match(/[^?\/]+/g)`

Comment: if, you wnat `/`, `?` then `str.match(/[^?\/]+|[?\/]/g)`

Answer (score 5):

While everyone tries to prove that escaping is necessary, let me show you a way to keep off the escaping hell: using a [RegExp constructor notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you avoid having to escape `/` and inside a character class, you will only have to escape `]` and sometimes `-`.

```js
var uri = '/some/random/path?param=1234'
var arr = uri.split(RegExp("[?/]"));
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + "</pre>"; // with empty
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr.filter(Boolean), 0, 4) + "</pre>"; // no empty
```

Note that you do not need a `/g` modifier with [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it is default behavior.

**Some more notes on escaping in JavaScript regex patterns**:

- `\` must always be escaped
- `?` must be escaped outside of a character class
- `/` must be escaped in a literal regex notation
- `[` must be escaped when outside of a character class
- `]` must be escaped inside a character class
- `+`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `.` must be escaped outside the character class and do not have to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Note that I do not think that a constructor notation is the best here, MDN suggests using literal notation for any known (non-dynamic) pattern. So, `/[?\/]/` is the best option here.

Answer (score 2):

Both `?` and `/` need to be escaped in your regex using `\`:

```js
let uri = '/some/random/path?param=1234'
let arr = uri.split(/\?|\//);
console.log(arr);
//arr = ["", "some", "random", "path", "param=1234"]
```

Comment: Not always should they be escaped.

Comment: `uri.split(/[?\/]/);`

Comment: Yes, Avinash, I am being picky with explanations, you know. I did not downvote, BTW. I just want explanations to be clear.

Comment: @stribizhev Given the OPs regex (_"in your regex")_, these characters must be escaped.  I'm not saying there's not a simpler regex that could be used instead, but I'm helping the OP see what's wrong with what was attempted.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Your regex should work, but single character alternations are not the best solutions. A character class is a more appropriate solution here.

Comment: @stribizhev Indeed.  I was in the process of expanding my answer, but lost heart/interest after the community reaction to my answer to the actual question asked... (_"I am not sure where and what to escape"_)

Answer (score 2):

In order to match the *literal* characters `/` and `?`, you'll need to escape them. To escape a special character, you should place a `\` in front of it. So `?` would become `\?`, and `/` would become `\/`.

In addition, you have some space characters in your regex as well -  unless you are actually trying to match blank spaces, you should leave them out. For example, `/abc /` will match the string `"abc "` - note the space character after the `abc`.

What you are left with is something similar to this:

```
var uri = '/some/random/path?param=1234'
var arr = uri.split(/\?|\//);
// ["", "some", "random", "path", "param=1234"]
```

Some reference links:

- [Special Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special)
- [Optional Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here it works.Check it

```
    var regex = /([\?|\/])\w+/g;
    var uri = "'/some/random/path?param=1234'";
    var final = uri.match(regex);
    console.log(final);
```

Comment: `|` inside a character class will match a literal `|`.